# Show drop down menu on mouse over

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to create drop down menu like this:

[image]

I want when I place the mouse over the text to see combo box which I can use to select a value. When I remove the mouse I want to see simple Label. How I can do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unhovered:

[image: xyzzy]

On Hover:

[image: xyzzy hover]

On Click and Choose:

[image: foobar select]

On Choice Complete:

[image: foobar]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Hoverboard extends Application {

    public class TextChooser extends StackPane {
        private Label label = new Label();
        private ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>();

        public TextChooser(String... options) {
            StackPane.setAlignment(label, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
            StackPane.setAlignment(combo, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

            label.textProperty().bind(
                combo.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
            );
            label.visibleProperty().bind(
                combo.visibleProperty().not()
            );
            label.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 9));

            combo.getItems().setAll(options);
            combo.getSelectionModel().select(0);
            combo.setVisible(false);

            label.setOnMouseEntered(event -> combo.setVisible(true));
            combo.showingProperty().addListener(observable -> {
                if (!combo.isShowing()) {
                    combo.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
            combo.setOnMouseExited(event -> {
                if (!combo.isShowing()) {
                    combo.setVisible(false);
                }
            });

            getChildren().setAll(label, combo);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TextChooser textChooser = new TextChooser(
            "xyzzy", "frobozz", "foobar"
        );

        VBox layout = new VBox(textChooser);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(Hoverboard.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is also css style version: https://github.com/varren/JavaFX-CSS-Styled-ComboBox-Demo

A little bit different from the default one, but you can play with css to get what you want. Default styles can be found in **jxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css**

***CSS***

```
#changed{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
#changed .arrow,
#changed .arrow-button{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}


/* this part is from  default stiles fxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css */
#changed:hover{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-radius: 5, 5, 4, 3;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}

#changed:showing > .arrow-button {
    -fx-color: -fx-pressed-base;
}

#changed:hover > .arrow-button > .arrow{
    -fx-background-insets: 1 0 -1 0, 0;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-mark-highlight-color, -fx-mark-color;
    -fx-padding: 0.166667em 0.333333em 0.166667em 0.333333em; /* 2 4 2 4 */
    -fx-shape: "M 0 0 h 7 l -3.5 4 z";
}
```

**JAVA**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        HBox root = new HBox();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Combo Box Style From Css");


        ComboBox combobox = new ComboBox<String>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("One", "Two", "Three"));
        combobox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        combobox.setId("changed");

        ComboBox normalCombobox = new ComboBox<String>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("One", "Two", "Three"));
        normalCombobox.getSelectionModel().select(0);

        root.getChildren().addAll(combobox, normalCombobox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
        scene.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        String css = Main.class.getResource("styles.css").toExternalForm();
        scene.getStylesheets().clear();
        scene.getStylesheets().add(css);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**DEMO**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Two potential approaches:

1. Try to use CSS to modify the look of the ComboBox so it looks like a normal text field; hide the arrow and border, and re-show them on :hover.  You'll want to lookup the CSS reference for ComboBox: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#combobox
2. Use a normal TextField, and display a border (and arrow) on :hover.  Attach a mouse-listener to the TextField to display a PopupControl on mouse click.  Put a ListView inside the PopupControl so it behaves like a ComboBox.  You'll need to create a class that implements Skin for your popup control.  You should be able to find some examples on the web.